LARAVEL orderBy DESC not working while using groupBy
I would like to use orderBy in laravel but its not working while I have used CAST there
    $this->adLists = ListingVisitor::with('listing')->selectRaw('CAST(sum(amount) as UNSIGNED) as total,listing_id,amount')->whereHas('listing.user',function($q){
        $q->where('id',Auth::user()->id);
    })->groupBy('listing_id')->orderBy('total','DESC')->paginate(10);

The result would be
136, 66, 1 ,5
Its actually should be 136, 66, 5, 1
I have using CAST in selectRaw but it has no difference

try ->orderByRaw('total DESC')

You can use DB::raw, This will solve any issue with ordering by the aliased column when using CAST in laravel
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$this->adLists = ListingVisitor::with('listing')
    ->select(DB::raw('CAST(SUM(amount) AS UNSIGNED) AS total'), 'listing_id', 'amount')
    ->whereHas('listing.user', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->groupBy('listing_id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('total'), 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
}


$this->adLists = ListingVisitor::with('listing')
    ->selectRaw('sum(amount) as total, listing_id')
    ->whereHas('listing.user', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->groupBy('listing_id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('sum(amount)'), 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10)

I think there is no requirement to cast it. When you do sum it already return you with the numeric format. Instead try to Order with the SUM function. It will give you the expected output.
